# mysql error while inserting values with parameters

Tags: mysql

```
write_command = 'insert into user_details values(?,?);'
values = (name, data)
my_cursor.execute(write_command, values)
my_sql.commit()
```

I am using both sqlite3 and mysql.connector for accessing SQL database

but sqlite3 accepts the above method of inserting values and not mysql.connector is accepting

i am not using .format here because i am inserting a file's data into sql. so, .format cannaot be used..

I am getting this error

```
raise errors.ProgrammingError(
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement
```

pls help me to find a way for inserting the values in both ways i.e. sqlite3 and mysql.connector with the same code
Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your **values(?,?)** to **VALUES (%s, %s)**

Comment: if i change like that sqlite3 will cause error like
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "%": syntax error

Comment: Then it sounds like you're going to have to check which database you're connecting to, and tailor your INSERT to that database. Not sure why you're using sqlite when mysql doesn't seem much more difficult, and I don't think sqlite is used in a production env very much.

Comment: Is this really two databases (sqllite and mysql), or are you simply trying to connect using both sqllite and mysql connector? If so, why???

Comment: yes it is two databases and I am doing like this because if I complete the program and compile it to exe then I will try to work with it on different devices that do not have an SQL server in it and i am using mysql also to view the changes which i have made to the table via workbench

Comment: But thanks for your replies, i just changed the code with try and except.....Thank you..